# Meaning of asterisk following table name in MS Access 2007

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-access-2007

In MS Access 2007, what does the asterisk indicate when it appears next to a table name in the Navigation Pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asterisk next to the table name indicates there are unsaved changes to that table.

Comment: I exit Access completely, re-open the database, and the asterisks remain.  Under which circumstances can you think of would the asterisks persist following a restart?  It is a local database.

Comment: If you go to the database and save it, does the asterisk remain?

Comment: Affirmative.  I click on the Office Button and the Save item is inactive.  I press Ctrl + S and nothing changes.  (Thanks for following up!)

Comment: Oh . . . my . . . god. . . .  Well, turns out that the table's *name* -- ITS NAME -- CONTAINS AN ASTERISK. . . .  Thanks anyway for your time, John.  (Suffice it to say that I did not create this database and was hired to migrate data out of it.)

Comment: Oh wow, looks like they did the right thing by replacing the last guy :)